# A precise way to define the Frechet topology on the space of $C^n$ mappings with values in a Frechet space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

To simplifiy the problem, let $V:=\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{T}, \mathbb{R})$ the real Frechet space of periodic smooth real-valued functions. Here, $\mathbb{T}:=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. We denote a generic element of $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ as "$x$".

Then, let
\begin{equation}
C\bigl([0,1], V\bigr)
\end{equation}
be the space of continuous mappings from $[0,1]$ into $V$. Here, continuity is with respect to the Frechet topology of $V$, of course.

Next, define inductively for $n=1,2,3, \cdots$,
\begin{equation}
C^n([0,1], V\bigr)
\end{equation}
as the space of continuous mappings $\phi(t) : [0,1] \to V$ which are also "jointly $C^n$" in $(t,x)$ as real-valued functions on $[0,1] \times \mathbb{T}$. we further require that each (usual) $l^{th}$ order time derivative of $\phi(t) \in C^n([0,1], V\bigr)$ belongs to $C^{n-l}([0,1], V\bigr)$ for $l=0,1,2, \cdots n$.

Now, my questions are as follows:

1. Is the above inductive construction well-defined?
2. Does each $C^n([0,1], V\bigr)$ become a Frechet space on its own? If so, how exactly should I describe its topology?

The reason I am considering $C^n([0,1], V\bigr)$ is that I wish to avoid the notion of Frechet derivatives in infinite dimensions as much as possible and just work with "usual"  derivatives. However, things seem a bit tricky..

Could anyone please clarify for me?